# How can I add a button in a fullcalendar correctly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I'm working with full calendar and I have this function:

```
calendar: function(datos,rut){

    var self = this;
    console.info(datos);
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({

        height: 500,
        events: datos,
        editable: true,

            header: {
                left: '',
                center: 'prev title next',
                right: '',
            },

        eventClick:  function(event) {
            $('#modalTitle').html(event.title);
            $('#modalBody').html(event.description);
            $('#eventUrl').attr('href',event.url);
            $('#fullCalModal').modal();
        },

        eventRender: function (event, element) {

            element.find('.fc-title').append(" (<strong>"+ event.estado +"</strong>)");

            var estado = event.estado;
            var date = event.title;
            var formatoFecha = date.substring(0,10);
            $('.fc-day-number[data-date='+formatoFecha+']').html("<div class=text-center><button type='button' style='margin-right:5px; padding:0; border: none; background: none;' id ='editar_control_"+formatoFecha+"_id' class='btn btn-default addButton' title='Ver/Editar'><i class='fa fa-eye'></i></button></div>");
            self.actionBtnCalendar(formatoFecha,rut,datos);


        }

    })

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents');
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', datos);         
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('rerenderEvents');        
},
```

and looks like:

[image]

The eye icon is a button, and it's fine, but the problem that is I'm using this:

```
$('.fc-day-number[data-date='+formatoFecha+']').html("<div class=text-center><button type='button' style='margin-right:5px; padding:0; border: none; background: none;' id ='editar_control_"+formatoFecha+"_id' class='btn btn-default addButton' title='Ver/Editar'><i class='fa fa-eye'></i></button></div>";
```

with html, so the days number disappear and if I use append , looks like this:

[image]

the numbers of eyes its the same that the numbers of event by day.

So I don't know how put correctly the button in each day that have a event, but outside, I need the same that the first picture but showing the numbers days.

I appreciate any advice or help , sorry my english.

**EDIT**

If I use dayRender:

```
eventRender: function (event, element) {

            element.find('.fc-title').append(" (<strong>"+ event.estado +"</strong>)");

            var estado = event.estado;
            var date = event.title;
            var formatoFecha = date.substring(0,10);
            //$('.fc-day-number[data-date='+formatoFecha+']').html("<div class=text-center><button type='button' style='margin-right:5px; padding:0; border: none; background: none;' id ='editar_control_"+formatoFecha+"_id' class='btn btn-default addButton' title='Ver/Editar'><i class='fa fa-eye'></i></button></div>");
            self.actionBtnCalendar(formatoFecha,rut,datos); 
        },

        dayRender: function (date, element) {
            $('.fc-day-number[data-date='+date+']').append("<div class=text-center><button type='button' style='margin-right:5px; padding:0; border: none; background: none;' id ='editar_control_"+date+"_id' class='btn btn-default addButton' title='Ver/Editar'><i class='fa fa-eye'></i></button></div>");
        }
```

nothing happens

Answer (score 0):

You get the results you see because you use the `eventRender` hook, in stead to display the button once for each day you should use the `dayRender` hook.
See [here](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/display/dayRender/).

```
dayRender: function (date, element) {
        $('.fc-day-number[data-date='+date+']').append("<div class=text-center><button type='button' style='margin-right:5px; padding:0; border: none; background: none;' id ='editar_control_"+date+"_id' class='btn btn-default addButton' title='Ver/Editar'><i class='fa fa-eye'></i></button></div>");
    }
```

Using this hook you can use `append` because it is only called once per day.

Comment: Hi, ty for u answer , I used dayRender but nothing happens, i don´t know why. I need add something else?

Comment: Could you verify that the `date` in the function points to the correct html object in your code, just perform some `console.logs` to see what is happening. (If you can provide a fiddle I can help you more easily)